# Permission error on SQL access by a web service C# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, permissions

When I try to access a SQL command by a web service developed in C# .Net I have this error.

The Web serice is called by a windows form application in C# too.

This is the error:

```
"Falha na solicitação da permissão de tipo 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,"
```

This is my code:

```
Sql query = new Sql();
StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();
comando.Append("SELECT EntCod FROM ENT001 T1 (NOLOCK) " +
               "WHERE T1.EntCpfCgc = @ENTCPFCGC ");
query.addParametro("ENTCPFCGC", CPFCGC);

DataTable resultado = query.Select(comando.ToString()).Tables[0];
```

The "SQL" class is a control class that connect on SQL server DB.

Comment: The user account under which the web service is running (or the username/password with which the service is using in the connection string, if using sql logins rather than windows authentication) does not have access to the sql server (no login or invalid login), and/or it does not have (at a minimum I would wager) read/write access to the database.  This is pretty much SOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve solved my problem with this DOS commands:

```
C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -machine -chggroup 1 FullTrust
C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -user -chggroup 1 FullTrust
C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -enterprise -chggroup 1 FullTrust
```

Giving "FullTrust" permissions on this file.

Thanks all for reply!